# Recursively Combining a node from two linked list into one node to build a new linked list

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

I'm having issues trying to write a function that takes in two linked lists, takes each node from both, combines them into a tuple, and builds a new linked list.

should print something like this:
(1, 2) -> (3, 4) -> (5, 6)

here's what I have and I'm getting errors whenever I run it

```
def pair(head_one, head_two):
if head_one is not None or head_two is not None:
    head = ListNode((head_one.val, head_two.val))
    head.next = pair(head_one.next.val, head_two.next.val)
    return head
else:
    return None
```

Comment: Please add the definition of the `ListNode` class to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your function expects its arguments to be two ListNode instances, but your recursive call passes on the `val` property...

So change this:

```
pair(head_one.next.val, head_two.next.val)
```

To this:

```
pair(head_one.next, head_two.next)
```

Comment: I tried this already, this is the error I keep on getting. "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'"

Comment: So what does your node look like? Did you debug? Is the property really called `val`, or is it `value`, or maybe `data`?

Comment: Did you miss my comment?

Comment: They also need to change the condition from `or` to `and` to handle the base case (to truncate if one list is longer). If OP wants to continue pairing even with one list shorter, need more case handling on that.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the  best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects.

Using a simple `node` class -

```py
class node:
  def __init__(self, val, next = None):
    self.val = val
    self.next = next
```

We write a `to_str` function and define two lists, `l1` and `l2` -

1. if the input list, `l`, is empty, return end of list, *"EOL"*
2. (inductive) `l` has at least one element. Get the `str` representation of the first element's value, `l.val`, and combine it with the recursive result of the sub-problem, `l.next`

```
def to_str(l):
  if not l:
    return "EOL"                                 # 1
  else:
    return str(l.val) + "->" + to_str(l.next)    # 2

l1 = node(1, node(3, node(5)))
l2 = node(2, node(4, node(6)))

print(to_str(l1))
print(to_str(l2))
```

```
1->3->5->EOL
2->4->6->EOL
```

Now we can write our `pairs` function -

1. if both input lists, `a` and `b`, are empty, the base we have reached the base case. Return an empty list
2. (inductive) Either `a` or `b` has at least one element. If `a` is empty, `b` has at least one element. Create a new node `(None, b.val)` and the recursive result of the sub-problem, `pairs(a, b.next)`
3. (inductive) `a` has at least one element. If `b` is empty, create a new node of `(a.val, None)` and the recursive result of the sub-problem, `pairs(a.next, b)`
4. (inductive) `a` and `b` have at least one element. Create a new node of `(a.val, b.val)` and the recursive result of the sub-problem, `pairs(a.next, b.next)`

```py
def pairs(a, b):
  if not a and not b:
    return None                                         # 1
  elif not a:
    return node((None, b.val), pairs(a, b.next))        # 2
  elif not b:
    return node((a.val, None), pairs(a.next, b))        # 3
  else:
    return node((a.val, b.val), pairs(a.next, b.next))  # 4
    
print(to_str(pairs(l1, l2)))
```

```
(1, 2)->(3, 4)->(5, 6)->EOL
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be like a zip() function for the linked lists:

Iteratively:

```
def linkedZip(A,B):
    result = tail = ListNode(None) # Empty "head" placeholder
    while A and B:
        tail.next = ListNode((A.val,B.val))  # pair and link values
        A,B,tail  = A.next,B.next,tail.next  # advance lists in parallel
    return result.next
```

or recursively:

```
 def linkedZip(A,B):
     if A and B: 
         paired      = ListNode((A.val,B.val))
         paired.next = linkedZip(A.next,B.next)
         return paired
```

and more concisely if the ListNode constructor accepts the next node:

```
 def linkedZip(A,B):
     if A and B: return ListNode((A.val,B.val),linkedZip(A.next,B.next))
```

If you need to zip to the longest length filling tuples with None beyond the end of the shorter list:

```
 def linkedZip_longest(A,B):
     if A or B:
         paired      = ListNode((A and A.val,B and B.val))
         paired.next = linkedZip_longest(A and A.next,B and B.next)
         return paired
```

or

```
     def linkedZip_longest(A,B):
     if A or B: return ListNode((A and A.val,B and B.val),
                                linkedZip_longest(A and A.next,B and B.next))
```